# Error when replicating to Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, replication, azure-sql-database, transactional-replication

I've configured transactional replication between my on-prem SQL 2017 instance and an Azure SQL Database. The publisher, distributor, subscriber have all been set up. The snapshot agent has generated a snapshot and the log reader agent is running without errors.

However, replication is failing with this error:

*The process could not connect to Subscriber 'MYDBSERVER.DATABASE.WINDOWS.NET'. (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL0)
Get help: http://help/MSSQL_REPL0
Unable to complete login process due to delay in opening server connection (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 08001)
Get help: http://help/08001*

I've added  a firewall rule and can connect to the Azure SQL instance using SSMS. The subscriber is also set up, so I don't think it's a firewall issue. The min TLS version is set to 1.0 which should be fine too.

The SQL Agent logs indicate that the command is retrying over and over. The only error is this:

*The replication agent encountered an error and is set to restart within the job step retry interval. See the previous job step history message or Replication Monitor for more information.*

The SQL Server logs only contain the following:

Replication-Replication Distribution Subsystem: agent .... scheduled for retry. The process could not connect to Subscriber 'MYDBSERVER.DATABASE.WINDOWS.NET'.

The job is configured to connect to the subscriber as the admin account, so permissions shouldn't be an issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried connecting to your Azure SQL instance via SSMS when logged into the machine for your on-prem SQL Server 2017 instance (as opposed from your own machine)?

Comment: Yes it works just fine.

Comment: I've set up a new instance on a VM running locally and replication works fine, so it appears to be a problem specifically related to the configuration of this instance.